# name for this "hold" line in contemporary music?

Tags: notation

is there a standardised name for these type of "hold" lines in contemporary music notation?
[image: hold line?]

I've googled around quite a bit but couldn't find a distinct name for this notation. Should I conclude that this is some personal invention by Robert Coinel (from which this image is taken [here](http://robertcoinel.com/images/PARTITIONS/haikus-pour-flute.pdf))?

Answer (score 12):

These thick horizontal lines are referred to as  "extenders" in [*Behind Bars - The Definitive Guide to Music Notation*](https://www.alfred.com/behind-bars/p/12-0571514561/) (p. 632).

Answer (score 6):

Gardner Read's term for thick horizontal lines like that, as well as similar innovations such as the posted example's eights-becoming-sixteenths beaming, is **time notation** (p. 72, *Music notation: a manual of modern practice*, 2nd ed., 1969).  He illustrates this with excerpts from Earle Brown's 1959 *Hodograph I* and Luciano Berio's 1960 *[Circles](http://www.lucianoberio.org/en/circles)*.

[Brown himself](https://earle-brown.org/work/hodograph-i/) calls this notation  **proportional**.

Answer (score 5):

LilyPond calls them [Duration lines](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/graphical-notation). I have no idea whether this is a standard term.